# Limit of summation of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-ik}$ series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I was wondering whether anyone was able to give some insight to determining the limit of the following summation

$$ 
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-ik}
$$

If anyone has any idea or is able to point me in the correct direction it would be greatly appreciated. I know I may have missed something very obvious but it's been a long time since I've done this type of Maths

Comment: This is an infinite geometric series with start value $1$ and $q:=e^{-k}$. The sum formula is (if $|q|<1$ (which is equivalent to $k>0$) just $\frac{1}{1-q}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple geometric sum. $e^{-k} < 1$ holds for $k > 0$, and in that case we can use the $\frac{1}{1-q}$ formula:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-ik} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-k}\right)^i = \frac{1}{1-e^{-k}}$$

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Much appreciated